# Coroutines execution time vs Callbacks execution time

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm reading "Functional Kotlin" book and I've just tried out some examples about concurrent programming in Kotlin from that book. I have the following implementations of concurrent code:

1. With callbacks:

```
package com.freesoft.functional.coroutines

import kotlin.concurrent.thread

class CallbacksMain

class CallbackUserClient(private val client: UserClient) {
    fun getUser(id: Int, callback: (User) -> Unit) {
        thread {
            callback(client.getUser(id))
        }
    }
}

class CallbackFactClient(private val client: FactClient) {
    fun get(user: User, callback: (Fact) -> Unit) {
        thread {
            callback(client.getFact(user))
        }
    }
}

class CallBackUserRepository(private val userRepository: UserRepository) {
    fun getUserById(id: UserID, callback: (User?) -> Unit) {
        thread {
            callback(userRepository.getUserById(id))
        }
    }

    fun insertUser(user: User, callback: () -> Unit) {
        thread {
            userRepository.insertUser(user)
            callback()
        }
    }
}

class CallBackFactRepository(private val factRepository: FactRepository) {
    fun getFactByUserId(id: Int, callback: (Fact?) -> Unit) {
        thread {
            callback(factRepository.getFactByUserID(id))
        }
    }

    fun insertFact(fact: Fact, callback: () -> Unit) {
        thread {
            factRepository.insertFact(fact)
            callback()
        }
    }
}

class CallBackUserService(
    private val userClient: CallbackUserClient,
    private val factClient: CallbackFactClient,
    private val userRepository: CallBackUserRepository,
    private val factRepository: CallBackFactRepository
) : UserService {
    override fun getFact(id: UserID): Fact {
        var aux: Fact? = null
        userRepository.getUserById(id) { user ->
            if (user == null) {
                userClient.getUser(id) { userFromClient ->
                    userRepository.insertUser(userFromClient) {}
                    factClient.get(userFromClient) { fact ->
                        factRepository.insertFact(fact) {}
                        aux = fact
                    }
                }
            } else {
                factRepository.getFactByUserId(id) { fact ->
                    if (fact == null) {
                        factClient.get(user) { factFromClient ->
                            factRepository.insertFact(factFromClient) {}
                            aux = factFromClient
                        }
                    } else {
                        aux = fact
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (aux == null) {
            Thread.sleep(2)
        }
        return aux!!
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun execute(userService: UserService, id: Int) {
        val (fact, time) = inTime {
            userService.getFact(id)
        }
        println("fact = $fact")
        println("time = $time ms.")
    }

    val userClient = MockUserClient()
    val callbackUserClient = CallbackUserClient(userClient)
    val factClient = MockFactClient()
    val callBackFactClient = CallbackFactClient(factClient)
    val userRepository = MockUserRepository()
    val callbackUserRepository = CallBackUserRepository(userRepository)
    val factRepository = MockFactRepository()
    val callBackFactRepository = CallBackFactRepository(factRepository)

    val callBackUserService = CallBackUserService(
        userClient = callbackUserClient,
        factClient = callBackFactClient,
        userRepository = callbackUserRepository,
        factRepository = callBackFactRepository
    )

    execute(callBackUserService, 1)
    execute(callBackUserService, 2)
    execute(callBackUserService, 1)
    execute(callBackUserService, 2)
    execute(callBackUserService, 3)
    execute(callBackUserService, 4)
    execute(callBackUserService, 5)
    execute(callBackUserService, 10)
    execute(callBackUserService, 100)
}
```

and 
2. With coroutines:

```
package com.freesoft.functional.coroutines

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class CoroutinesUserService(
    private val userClient: UserClient,
    private val factClient: FactClient,
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val factRepository: FactRepository
) : UserService {
    override fun getFact(id: UserID): Fact = runBlocking {
        val user = async { userRepository.getUserById(id) }.await()
        if (user == null) {
            val userFromService = async { userClient.getUser(id) }.await()
            launch { userRepository.insertUser(userFromService) }
            getFact(userFromService)
        } else {
            async {
                factRepository.getFactByUserID(id) ?: getFact(user)
            }.await()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getFact(user: User): Fact {
        val fact: Deferred<Fact> = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            async { factClient.getFact(user) }
        }
        coroutineScope {
            launch { factRepository.insertFact(fact.await()) }
        }
        return fact.await()

    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun execute(userService: UserService, id: Int) {
        val (fact, time) = inTime {
            userService.getFact(id)
        }
        println("fact = $fact")
        println("time = $time ms.")
    }

    val userClient = MockUserClient()
    val factClient = MockFactClient()
    val userRepository = MockUserRepository()
    val factRepository = MockFactRepository()

    val coroutinesUserService = CoroutinesUserService(userClient, factClient, userRepository, factRepository)

    execute(coroutinesUserService, 1)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 2)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 1)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 2)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 3)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 4)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 5)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 10)
    execute(coroutinesUserService, 100)
}

Here are the mocks that I'm using `UserClient,FactClient,UserRepository and FactRepository`:

class MockUserClient : UserClient {
    override fun getUser(id: UserID): User {
        println("MockUserClient.getUser")
        Thread.sleep(500)
        return User(id, "Foo", "Bar", Gender.FEMALE)
    }
}

class MockFactClient : FactClient {
    override fun getFact(user: User): Fact {
        println("MockFactClient.getFact")
        Thread.sleep(500)
        return Fact(Random().nextInt(), "FACT ${user.firstName}, ${user.lastName}", user)
    }
}

class MockUserRepository : UserRepository {
    private val users = hashMapOf<UserID, User>()

    override fun getUserById(id: UserID): User? {
        println("MockUserRepository.getUserById")
        Thread.sleep(200)
        return users[id]
    }

    override fun insertUser(user: User) {
        println("MockUserRepository.insertUser")
        Thread.sleep(200)
        users[user.id] = user
    }
}

class MockFactRepository : FactRepository {
    private val facts = hashMapOf<UserID, Fact>()

    override fun getFactByUserID(userID: UserID): Fact? {
        println("MockFactRepository.getFactByUserId")
        Thread.sleep(200)
        return facts[userID]
    }

    override fun insertFact(fact: Fact) {
        println("MockFactRepository.insertFact")
        Thread.sleep(200)
        facts[fact.user?.id ?: 0] = fact
    }
}
```

My question is: why the implementation with coroutines is more time expensive even if the total sum of the requests to mock objects should be around 1.2 seconds? In the callback implementation I receive a correct execution time (1.2 sec) but in the coroutine implementation I receive about 1.4 sec as execution time.

Comment: I think this happens because coroutines by default are more advanced as construct, callbacks are just function calls. 2 requests are not indicator of performance, try to benchmark it with more requests, there shouldn't be much of performance degradation and remember that `Thread.sleep` blocks the entire thread, use `delay()` instead.

Comment: I can't use delay because I'm not in a coroutineScope. Thread.sleep it's ok because it's mocking a real I/O (for example) operation.I know that 2 requests are not an indicator, but I have mocked requests that are executing only in memory and I should receive the same processing time as the callbacks execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two misconceptions here:

1. Coroutines are faster than threads
2. That you're actually using coroutines efficiently

Let's start with the first one.
Coroutines are not faster than threads. They are more concurrent, though. It means that if you have thousands of coroutines, you'll still be fine. If you have thousands of threads - you'll be running out of memory.

But your test is not aggressive at all:

```
execute(callBackUserService, 1)
execute(callBackUserService, 2)
execute(callBackUserService, 1)
execute(callBackUserService, 2)
execute(callBackUserService, 3)
execute(callBackUserService, 4)
execute(callBackUserService, 5)
execute(callBackUserService, 10)
execute(callBackUserService, 100)
```

Even when you start 6 threads for each `execute`, it doesn't result in enough overhead. Do something like

```
 repeat(100_000) {
     execute(callBackUserService, 100)
 }
```

And you'll see the difference.

Not let's go the the second point.

```
override fun getFact(id: UserID): Fact = runBlocking {
    val user = async { userRepository.getUserById(id) }.await()
    ...
}
```

What `runBlocking` does is blocks your calling execution context. Since you're on `main` thread, there's only a single thread you're running on. And by using `async {}.await()` on the same like, you're not benefiting from any concurrency, since you run your task on a thread, then immediately block it.

Once you're past those two concurrency problems, there's a third one that awaits you: `Thread.sleep(200)` in your mocks.

What you probably expect is that each coroutine will be blocked for 200ms. What actually will happen is that **all** coroutines are blocked for 200ms, since they share same execution pool. If you want to test your mocks with coroutines, you must use `delay()`, otherwise, you're not testing anything.

Comment: Thank you ! I've tried to figure out how coroutines are working for real and I was shocked because I couldn't understand why they are slower than actual threads. I was knowing all the theory behind it, but using the API was not giving me the same results as in theory. Also, coroutines were an experimental project for long time with lots of changes from a version to another.